# React js CSS loading issue with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, webpack

I'm facing CSS loading issue in setting up my React application using Node.js and Express.js. Here is my code:

**Webapck:**

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'production',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  entry: './server/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
  },
  plugins: [
    // new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],  
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
            options: { 
                insert: 'head', // insert style tag inside of <head>
                injectType: 'singletonStyleTag' // this is for wrap all your style in just one style tag
            },
          },
          "css-loader",
        ],
        sideEffects: true, 
        include: __dirname
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              '@babel/preset-react',
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
    modules: [
      'node_modules'
    ]
  },
};
```

**index.js (Server Code)**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5005;
const path = require('path');
var ReactDomServer = require('react-dom/server');
import Hello from '../ui.src/hello';
var cors = require('cors');
const axios = require('axios');
// import '../ui.src/assets/css/style.css';

app.use(cors())

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    const component = ReactDomServer.renderToString(<Hello />);
    res.send(`<html><body class='testclass'>${component}</body></html>`);
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server now listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

**React component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './assets/css/style.css';

const Hello = () => {
    return (
      <h1>Hello World this is Test File....</h1>
    )
}

export default Hello;
```

All my components are working fine, and via expess js I"m able to render the React component as well but it's not loading the CSS. Tried all the options but no luck. Please do suggest if anything missing.

Thank you in advance.